# JavaScript and CSS File Contents are Changing when https is used

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I stop ASP.NET from modifying the requested file?

I activated HTTPS on a web server and the CSS and JavaScript served by that server is getting change. When I navigate to the web page, the file is requested, but the body of the file has been modified. HTTPS was activated by using the securitySwitch of the web.config.

For example, the url of the file is: https://sample.com/css/site.css

This is the contents that is getting sent back:

```
<html><head><title></title><script language="javascript">window.location = 'http://sample.com/css/site.css';</script></head><body></body></html>
```

But on the server the file contains valid css. When the file is requested with http://sample.com/css/site.css the correct file is returned.

**Update**

I originally thought the problem was caused by IIS. But after more reading and diagnostics I found the error was caused by ASP.NET. This led me to a web.config change recently and a similar post here: [Resources not automatically loaded from Https - SecuritySwitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109410/resources-not-automatically-loaded-from-https-securityswitch) so I added the suggested ignores to the web.config and that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

use protocol-relative paths with https.
your include line should contain

```
//sample.com/css/site.css
```

and not

```
http://sample.com/css/site.css
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.